# How to run this mysql query with dynamically update the value?

Tags: php, mysql

```
update new_calls_display set city_id = '3' where cus_city like '%Madurai%'
```

above mysql query i want to change the city_id value dynamically and also corresponding cus_city also change dynamically from the current table(new_calls_display) using php coding

```
city_id             cus_city
1                Chennai
2                Ariyalur
2                Ariyalur
3                Madurai
3                Madurai
3                Madurai
1                Chennai
1                Chennai
```

like above table cus_id 1 to 50 so cus_city also 50 unique values

Comment: We need way more detail and examples.

Comment: ask your doubt about the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update new_calls_display 
set city_id = (
select  col_name from table_name where cus_city like '%Madurai%'   )
```

Comment: the cus_city madurai also change dynamically corresponding cus_id...(php/mysql) how to use looping concept for both cus_city, cus_id change dynamically

Comment: use ,  " 
where cus_city like  LIKE '%' ||  cus_city || '%' "

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a variable then concat it to the sql query string :

```
$idcity = 2;

"update new_calls_display set city_id = {$idcity} where cus_city like '%Madurai%'"
```

Don't forget to take care of the sql injections, the previous code can be hacked easely.